# Ubuntu's history keeps popping up

Tags: 22.04, history, bash-history

I've got a problem with my Ubuntu 22.04. I want to clear out the command line history, so I type 'history -c' and everything seems fine, I type 'history' and it's all cleard. Then, I logout and shutdown, log in again and  type 'history' once again and I'm back to square one with all my previous commands from the previous sessions.

I've already tried typing varieties of commands:

```
cat /dev/null > ~/.bash_history

cat /dev/null > ~/.bash_history && history -c && exit

echo > ./.bash_history
```

but nothing works. Thanks in advance, cheers

Comment: Make sure you are dealing with the right file with `echo "$HISTFILE"` ... you only need `> file` to empty a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `history -c && history -w`

From `history --help`:

```
Options:
  -c    clear the history list by deleting all of the entries

  -w    write the current history to the history file
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the history is stored in .bash_history, you can try the following command:

```
rm ~/.bash_history && touch ~/.bash_history
```

This will remove the bash history file and create a new (and empty) one. I don't know if this is THE way to clear the history file, but it should work in every mayor Linux distro (including Ubuntu)

Comment: Seems logical to me, but for some reason does not work. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Use the above mentioned command adding 'sudo'.

Comment: I did it even as root - the same outcome